# How to access div inside Google Maps InfoBox

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Is there a way to access a div inside an InfoBox? The following code works with standard InfoWindow:

```
content = '<div id="#map_wrapper">THIS IS A CONTENT</div>';
infowindow.setContent(content);
infowindow.setPosition(cluster.getCenter());
infowindow.open(map);
console.log($('#map_wrapper').html());
```

With an InfoBox though, `$('#map_wrapper').html()` returns `null`. Is there a way to access `#map_wrapper`?

Thanks!

[ simon.cpu ]

Comment: You won't be able to access the infobox div unless it's opened on the Map. This is because the Google Maps API removes the infobox div from the DOM when it's not displayed, and appends it to the correct position on the map when it's triggered open.

So unfortunately there is no way of accessing the `#map_wrapper` if the infobox is in a closed state.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$(infowindow.getContent()).find('#map_wrapper')
```